# Flutter: Move dialog up to make room for soft keyboard?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to move a Dialog (an `AlertDialog` in my case) up to make room for the soft keyboard when it is visible?

[image: Login dialog - keyboard hidden]
[image: Login dialog - keyboard is hiding text field]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7032

There's a workaround in that bug if that helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late response - I only now remembered to actually try it! Works perfectly, now I just may have to add some scrolling ability to my dialog...

Comment: It woks but you need to change
mediaQuery.padding
by
mediaQuery.viewInsets

Answer (score 19):

add this margin `margin: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,` , it worked for me in a custom Alert Dialog .

Answer (score 4):

try this..

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: yourFocus.hasFocus ? 
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 250 // adjust values according to your need
                        : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 130),// adjust values according to your need
                child: AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("your Alert header text"),
                    content: TextField(
                             focusNode: yourFocus,
                             controller: yourTextController,
                             decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                                        hintText: "your hint text."),
                             ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                          child: Text("Your button Title"),
                          onPressed: () {
                           yourFunction();
                          })
                    ]));
```

Answer (score 4):

this is my answer:

wrap your dialog with Padding widget.
and then give property

> padding: EdgeInsets.only(
> bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),

```
Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom), 
          child: Center(
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: ScaleTransition(
                scale: scaleAnimation,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0))),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 30.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                              child: Text(
                            "Masukkan password akun anda",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 16.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    width: 1
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)
                                ),
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:10,vertical:5)
                              ),
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              obscureText: true,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 22,
                                letterSpacing: 1
                              ),
                            ),
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: ButtonTheme(
                                  height: 35.0,
                                  minWidth: 110.0,
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                                    splashColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(40),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'OK',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 13.0),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                      widget.nextPage();
                                    },
                                  )),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 20.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                              child:  ButtonTheme(
                                  height: 35.0,
                                  minWidth: 110.0,
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    color: Colors.red[700],
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                                    splashColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(40),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Batal',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 13.0),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ))
                            ),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issues by using this in Scaffold. I am able to fix it.

> resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,

According to Documentation --

If true the [body] and the scaffold's floating widgets should size themselves to avoid the onscreen keyboard whose height is defined by the ambient [MediaQuery]'s [MediaQueryData.viewInsets] bottom property.

For example, if there is an onscreen keyboard displayed above the scaffold, the body can be resized to avoid overlapping the keyboard, which prevents widgets inside the body from being obscured by the keyboard.

Defaults to true.

```
Scaffold(
.......
 resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code block with Dialog(child: _your_pop_up_widget());

Answer (score 0):

you can use showGenerlDialog with keyboard awareness like below,

- what happens below is im using viewInset coming from keyboard with Animation and scroll view

  ```
    showGeneralDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierLabel: "Barrier",
    barrierDismissible: false,
    barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
    transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
      return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, _) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
          },
          child: AnimatedPadding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,top: 40),
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
            curve: Curves.easeOut,
            child:  SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 336.w,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    child: Material(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
                            },
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.close,
                                size: 25.w,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
        );
      });
    },
    transitionBuilder: (context, a1, a2, widget) {
      return Transform.scale(
        scale: a1.value,
        child: Opacity(
          opacity: a1.value,
          child: widget,
        ),
      );
    },
  );
  ```